# One problem about tower stability

Tags: classical-mechanics, stability

Some years ago i asked myself a question that I still can not answer. Here it is:

A given tower consists of finite homogeneous cubic blocks staying one on another and equal to each other. What is the condition for stability of such tower?

First one can consider 2-dimensional analogue of this problem where 2-dimensional tower is staying on a real line.

Comment: On the other hand, it is also possible make problem harder considering not a queue-tower which i meant in the beginning but more complicated towers with more than one cube in each stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Stability**

For all $k$ up to the total number of blocks $n$:  the center of mass of the top $k$ blocks must lie above the surface of the $k+1$ block supporting them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think it is right.

Comment: I have a PhD in Physics and was a professor of physics for years, so frankly I do know this stuff.  You can get a mathematical treatment of the greatest overhang possible by searching "greatest overhanging blocks physics."